# What technology does google use for OCR in Google Drive

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

I need to use an OCR library and have been trying to use Tesseract. The problem is that the accuracy of Tesseract on a few test images is not very good. I'm not able to improve the quality of the images either as they are going to be submitted by users.

However, when I uploaded the file using the OCR feature in GoogleDocs it was able to read the image perfectly. I was wondering whether there a google OCR library, I know it has been improving Tesseract, or is the Google OCR library strictly proprietary (I presume it is)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to have a good result and good detection, you may need to improve the detection by using some filters and automatic thresholding.  You can try PILLOW library for filters and image manipulation.